# Firefox only loads 500 KB

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, backbone.js, limit

I´m working on a big SPA (Single-Page-Application).

In this Project, I have do load a large initialization-data-object (json) , which has a filesize of about 1.5 MB.This json-object is filled with large integer arrays of timestamps and other numeric data. As MVC-framework I use backbone.js so I fetch this data with model.fetch(...) 
In Chrome and Internet Explorer (yes really `:-)`) this works without problems, but firefox only loads about 500 KB of this data.

For me, it looks like a problem with the configuration of my firefox. Have you any idea, how I can fix this?

Comment: There is no way we can help you unless you provide a self contained test case. Maybe reproduce a small section on JSFiddle with just loading some data object?

Comment: edit that into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reinstalling Firefox. It seemd to be a problem with the configuration. Now Firefox also loads all data.

Answer (score 0):

If this data is receiving only on initialize, try to load it with html. Insert your data direct into document body when server generates page, and use it for your needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bigData = JSON.parse('{"my":"x","big":1000,"data":["y","z"]}');
</script>
```

In this case, your profit is:

- single request to database on page generating;
- time economy for requests to the server on backbone-fetch;
- solution for mozilla limit;